# How to implement Donald Knuth's up-arrow notation

Tags: custom-notation, number-representation

How does one enter very large numbers in [up-arrow notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnuthsUp-ArrowNotation.html)? Up-arrow notation was created by Donald Knuth to write very large numbers in it iterated exponentiation form, for example 6↑↑3 = 6^6^6.

Comment: Should that not be 6↑↑3 = 6^6^6?

Comment: @TeakeNutma is correct, the question should be edited. Unfortunately I can't do it myself because "[e]dits must be at least 6 characters" and there is only a single character to be added.

Answer (score 22):

```
UpArrow[a_, n_Integer] := Nest[a^# &, 1, n]
```

then

```
UpArrow[4, 3]
```

or

```
4 \[UpArrow] 3
```

[image]

---

To complete this method you may wish to add an input alias:

```
AppendTo[CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, InputAliases], "up" -> "\[UpArrow]"];
```

Now <kbd>Esc</kbd>`up`<kbd>Esc</kbd> will enter `\[UpArrow]`.

Change `$FrontEndSession` to `$FrontEnd` and run it only once to make the change persist between sessions.

Comment: UpArrow can be used directly. Hope you do not mind the edit.

Comment: Also relevant http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html

Comment: This isn't correct, a single up arrow is power, two is tetration, etc... see Teake Nutma answer.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a more general variant a(↑...↑)b with any given number of up-arrows, as defined on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnuthsUp-ArrowNotation.html):

```
(* Short-hand for single arrow. *)
UpArrow[a_, b_]    := UpArrow[1][a, b];
(* Trivial case of a(↑...↑)1. *)
UpArrow[_][a_, 1]  := a;
(* Single arrow: exponentation. *)
UpArrow[1][a_, b_] := a^b;
(* Generic case: do a recursion. *)
UpArrow[n_Integer][a_, b_Integer] /; n > 1 := 
  Nest[UpArrow[n - 1][a, #] &, a, b - 1];

(* And some nice formatting. *)
MakeBoxes[UpArrow[n_][a_, b_], StandardForm] :=
  RowBox@{
    MakeBoxes[a],
    SuperscriptBox["\[UpArrow]", MakeBoxes[n]],
    MakeBoxes[b]
  };
```

The `UpArrow[n][a,b]` notation may look a bit clumsy (as opposed to say `UpArrow[a,b,n]`), but it makes the use of Infix notation much more natural:

[image: Knuth's up-arrow examples]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Notation` package to make the input of Knuth-style numbers very easy.

Load the notation package, which will make a `Notation` palette appear at the top-right of your screen.

```
<< Notation`
```

Use the second entry in the `Notation` palette (you have to do it this way) to define a new input notation.

```
Notation[a_\[UpArrow]n_ \[DoubleLongRightArrow] Nest[a_^#&,1,n_]]
```

This uses a pattern that is inspired by the `UpArrow` function defined in the answer given by Szabolcs.

Test that this new input notation works.

```
6\[UpArrow]3 == 6^6^6

(* True *)
```

You can define an input alias for entering `\[UpArrow]` in order to make things even more user-friendly.

Comment: Is there any reason to do this?  Using the built-in associated Symbol `UpArrow` seems like a much better option.

Comment: As you say, `↑` is already associated with `UpArrow`, so you don't actually need to associate it again using `Notation` — my suggested use of `Notation` is thus redundant in this case. However, I never pass up the opportunity to fly the flag for the wonderful but underused `Notation` package — more people need to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `Fold` equivalent of Szabolcs' answer:

```
UpArrow[a_, n_Integer] := Fold[#2^#1 &, 1, ConstantArray[a, n]]
```

Then

```
UpArrow[4, 3]
```

> 1340780792994259709957402499820584612747936582059239337772356144372176\
>   4030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946\
>   433649006084096